# How do I make a greyscale layer become a mask for another layer in Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, mask

I wanted to create a mask that looked exactly like another layer that I have. How do I do that?

Comment: You can place the layer you want to show directly above the greyscale layer, select the upper layer and create a clipping mask.

Comment: Do you mind posting an example of what you have tried so we can provide a better answer?

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all copy your layer to the clipboard (it will be your mask)
2. Add a layer mask on the layer where mask must be aplied
3. Open Channels palette and select your mask channel. Make it visible ("eye" mark)
4. Paste from clipboard the previously copied image.

In CS4 it was a bit easier :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `Channels` palette. Hold <kbd>Ctrl/Option</kbd> and click on the RGB thumb. Now you have a selection that you can apply as a mask to any of your layers.

If you want just one layer, single it out by holding <kbd>Ctrl/Option</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> and clicking the eye icon of that layer, then the same ...

`Channels`, <kbd>Ctrl/Option</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd>, make mask.